# Test phantom-read and dirty-read in Springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, spring-data

Phantom-read and Dirty-read are one of the biggest pitfalls for beginners, however they can be managed by setting isolation-level of transactions.

you might argue that they can be controlled by spring-boot. so there is no need for a test. but as far as I know not all databases support isolation level. So, how we can simulate them in springboot's tests?

Comment: So you want to set the isolation to TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli No, I want to write a test to simulate the problem of phantom or dirty read.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to test. you say: "Phantom-read and Dirty-read are one of the biggest pitfalls for beginners" Why do you think so? That's IMHO not true because you have to change the isolation level. And that's nothing a beginner will do

Comment: @SimonMartinelli and exactly that is why I say that because beginners are not aware of them. As a result, they develope their app in the wrong way and that lead to serious problems for them. I know you can set the isolation level but what I am talking about is not set it, it is about how we can provide a situation in a test that such things happen and test our code against it.

Comment: That's not possible to get into this situation without setting the isolation level to TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED. The default is READ_COMMITED and then you don't have this problems

Answer (score 2):

I simulate the dirty-read, unrepeatable-read, phantom-read, lost-update in SpringBoot by JUnit5.

The test results are as follows

1. SQL Server:

| Isolation Level | Dirty Read | Unrepeatable Read | Phantom Read | Lost Update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEFAULT | not occur | may occur | may occur | may occur |
| READ_UNCOMMITTED | may occur | may occur | may occur | may occur |
| READ_COMMITTED | not occur | may occur | may occur | may occur |
| REPEATABLE_READ | not occur | not occur | may occur | not occur |
| SERIALIZABLE | not occur | not occur | not occur | not occur |

2. MySQL

| Isolation Level | Dirty Read | Unrepeatable Read | Phantom Read | Lost Update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEFAULT | not occur | not occur | may occur | may occur |
| READ_UNCOMMITTED | may occur | may occur | may occur | may occur |
| READ_COMMITTED | not occur | may occur | may occur | may occur |
| REPEATABLE_READ | not occur | not occur | may occur | may occur |
| SERIALIZABLE | not occur | not occur | not occur | not occur |

3. PostgreSQL

| Isolation Level | Dirty Read | Unrepeatable Read | Phantom Read | Lost Update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEFAULT | not occur | may occur | may occur | may occur |
| READ_UNCOMMITTED | not occur | may occur | may occur | may occur |
| READ_COMMITTED | not occur | may occur | may occur | may occur |
| REPEATABLE_READ | not occur | not occur | not occur | not occur |
| SERIALIZABLE | not occur | not occur | not occur | not occur |

4. H2

| Isolation Level | Dirty Read | Unrepeatable Read | Phantom Read | Lost Update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEFAULT | not occur | may occur | may occur | may occur |
| READ_UNCOMMITTED | may occur | may occur | may occur | may occur |
| READ_COMMITTED | not occur | may occur | may occur | may occur |
| REPEATABLE_READ | not occur | not occur | not occur | may occur |
| SERIALIZABLE | not occur | not occur | not occur | may occur |

The JUnit5 testing example
[image]

You can refer to this project in [here](https://github.com/changemyminds/Transaction-Isolation-Level-Issue).