# Is isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ enough to transfer money from account to account?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, transactions, spring-transactions

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
    override fun transfer(transfer: Transfer) {
        val accountFrom = accountRepository.findByAccount(transfer.from)
            .orElseThrow { EntityNotFoundException("no such account: ${transfer.from}") }
        val accountTo = accountRepository.findByAccount(transfer.to)
            .orElseThrow { EntityNotFoundException("no such account: ${transfer.to}") }
        if (accountFrom.value < transfer.value)
            throw NotEnoughFundsOnFromAccount(transfer.from)
        accountFrom.value=accountFrom.value.minus(transfer.value)
        accountTo.value=accountTo.value.plus(transfer.value)
        accountRepository.save(accountFrom)
        accountRepository.save(accountTo)
    }
```

Is `isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ` enough to perform money transfer from account to account (Of course all of above is for multithreaded implementation)? Or do I need some synchronization accounts code?

Comment: What kind of transactional problems do you want to avoid? `Dirty Read` or `Lost Update` ?

Comment: Ether `Dirty Read` and `Lost Update` are avoid by `Isolation.READ_COMMITTED`, Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ is for repeatable read )))

Comment: `Isolation.READ_COMMITTED` can avoid `Dirty Read`. But the `Lost Update` need according to the type of database. In `MySQL` Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ may occur `Lost Update`.

Comment: `Lost Update` is the lowest anomaly level and any transaction avoid it

Comment: Have you tried simulated transaction? Because recently I have same problem about isolation level so I deep study and try to simulate. You can see the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67314386/5046887). If my concept is wrong, please let me know.